# Missing Time::Piece on Perl 5.10

Tags: perl, datetime

I am reading that Perl 5.10 already has the `Time::Piece` module installed on it. I am working on another Linux computer that doesn't have internet capabilities and has Perl 5.10 installed. I wrote a program that uses `Time::Piece` and am getting this error when I run it on that machine.

```
Cant locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/
x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

It then lists some more folders and says the error occurs at the line I say `use Time::Piece`

Like I said I don't have internet access on that machine so I can't just run a command to update it. I guess I need to download the `Time::Piece` module onto a USB and update it manually?

Comment: How was that version of Perl installed on that system? Seems likely that the installation is broken in interesting ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>`Time::Piece` was introduced to core Perl in v5.10.1. If you have v5.10.0 then you are just out of luck</strike>

You can download the installation package on an internet-connected PC [from here](https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/R/RJ/RJBS/Time-Piece-1.30.tar.gz) onto, say, a flash drive, and follow the instructions in [`perlmodinstall`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html) to install it onto your target system

Comment: Time::Piece was [definitely included in Perl 5.10.0](https://metacpan.org/source/RGARCIA/perl-5.10.0/ext/Time/Piece/Piece.pm). I'd be deeply suspicious of any installation of 5.10 that didn't include it.

Comment: You're quite right. I was working from memory, but `corelist` says it came in v5.9.5. I'm pretty sure there is a core module that was introduced in v5.10.1 though

Comment: I think you're thinking of autodie.

Comment: @DaveCross: Most likely. Thanks Dave

Answer (score 1):

Some OS distributors (e.g. Fedora) have split the `perl` distribution into multiple packages. Use your OS's package manager (`apt-get`, `yum`, etc) to install the missing package.

Comment: hmm so you're saying that I do have Time::Piece on the computer but its not installed?

Comment: It would more likely be fetched for you from a online repository, though there are surely ways of downloading the package and installing it offline.